# jquery .remove() problems

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

ok. i have a dropdown menu. if i select student. an additional field should be added to the form and when i choose teacher..the student specific fields should be remove and teacher input fields should be added.. in short **i want to remove #student_profile if i choose #teacher_profile, and vice versa.**

heres my code:
**Javascript**

```
<script>
$(function() {
    $(".fields").hide();
    $("#role").change(function() {
        switch($(this).val()){ 
            case "3":
                $(".fields").hide().parent().find("#student_profile").show();
                .find("#teacher_profile").addClass('not-active');
                break;
            case "2":
                $(".fields").hide().parent().find("#teacher_profile").show();
                .find("#student_profile").addClass('not-active');

                break;
            }
        });
    });   
    $('#submit').click(function(){
    $('div').remove('.not-active');
    });
</script>
```

**html form**

```
<form action="add" method="post"/>

<h3><a href="#">User</a></h3>
<div><input id="username" name="username"/></div>
<div><label for="password">Password </label> <input name="password" type="password"/></div>
div><label for="role">Role </label>
<select id="role" name="role" class="medium">
<optgroup label="Type of User">
<option value="3" />Student
<option value="2" />Teacher
 </optgroup>
</select>
</div>

<div id="student_profile" class="fields">
<div class="field">
<label for="type">Course</label>
<select id="type" name="stdntCourse" class="medium">
<optgroup  label="Choose Course">
<option value="BS IT" />BS IT
<option value="BS CS" />BS CS
<option value="BS IS" />BS IS
</optgroup>
</select>
</div>
</div>
<div id="teacher_profile" class="fields">
<div class="field">
<label for="type">Department/label>
<select id="type" name="stdntCourse" class="medium">
<optgroup  label="Choose Course">
<option value="BS IT" />cas
<option value="BS CS" />education
<option value="BS IS" />engineering
</optgroup>
</select>
</div>
</div>
<input type="submit" id="submit" value="Add User"/>
</form>
```

Comment: what is the problem you are having

Comment: is not very clear. Do you want to remove the whole element? Or just the class attribute?

Comment: i did use remove class but no effect?..for example i choose student, but the teacher input is still submitted with blank value

Comment: i want to remove #student_profile if i choose #teacher_profile, and vice versa.

Comment: Is that ".find" syntax correct? your not referencing anything

Comment: Are you sure you dont want to just hide the profile rather than removing it? Is that not the point of 'not-active'?

Comment: yes i am sure.. because user can be a student or a teacher.. not both. if i choose student.. he/she should only have student profile, and same for the other, if i choose teacher, he/she should only have teacher profile.

Comment: Ah ok, well in that case have you tried ('#teacher_profile').remove(); and vice versa in your switch statement

Comment: yeah i tried that earlier.. didnt work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your html code is quite a mess (***invalid***) (*wrong nesting, wrong self closing tags etc..*)

```
<form action="add" method="post">

<h3><a href="#">User</a></h3>

    <div><input id="username" name="username"/></div>
    <div>
        <label for="password">Password </label>
        <input name="password" type="password" />
    </div>
    <label for="role">Role </label>
    <select id="role" name="role" class="medium">
        <optgroup label="Type of User">
            <option value="3">Student</option>
            <option value="2">Teacher</option>
         </optgroup>
    </select>

    <div id="student_profile" class="fields">
        <div class="field">
            <label for="type">Course</label>
            <select id="type" name="stdntCourse" class="medium">
                <optgroup  label="Choose Course">
                    <option value="BS IT">BS IT</option>
                    <option value="BS CS">BS CS</option>
                    <option value="BS IS">BS IS</option>
                </optgroup>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="teacher_profile" class="fields">
        <div class="field">
            <label for="type">Department</label>
            <select id="type" name="stdntCourse" class="medium">
                <optgroup  label="Choose Course">
                    <option value="BS IT">cas</option>
                    <option value="BS CS">education</option>
                    <option value="BS IS">engineering</option>
                </optgroup>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
    <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Add User" />

</form>
```

In your jquery you have some issues becaus eyou use the `;` at wrong places making syntax-errors

Here is a bit simplified version

```
$(function() {
    $(".fields").hide();
    $("#role").change(function() {
        switch(this.value){
            case "3":
                $(".fields").hide()
                            .filter('#student_profile')
                            .show()
                            .removeClass('not-active')
                            .end()
                            .filter('#teacher_profile')
                            .addClass('not-active');
                break;
            case "2":
                $(".fields").hide()
                            .filter('#teacher_profile')
                            .show()
                            .removeClass('not-active')
                            .end()
                            .filter('#student_profile')
                            .addClass('not-active');
                break;
                    }
    }).change();

    $('#submit').click(function(){
        $('div').remove('.not-active');
    });
});
```

You also need to invoke the `.change()` at the first time manually to initialize the form.

Working demo at http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/qTgGY/1/

Comment: @kester, if you examine the posted data from the form, you will see that only student **or** teacher data is being sent. The problem most likely lies in your PHP code and how you save the incoming data in the database. Can you show that part of your code ?

Comment: @kester, are you sure that the course field should be named `stdntCourse` for both teacher and student ? the prefix `stdnt` looks to refer to student only.. could that be the issue ? In your PHP you should differentiate based on the role.

Comment: i did check my php code.. the problem is in my php. sorry mate. thanks!